# How can I get a collection and a Model in one Action in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, http-post, http-method

How can I get a collection and a Model in one Action in MVC (http Post)?

Comment: Please provide more details. Your question is a little short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, if I got you right. But you could use a class wrapping it. The class gets a property for the collection and another one for the model and works as the new model then.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand what you need correctly i think that you can add the collection to the model then send it